# d3 tree separate tree layout and annotation

Tags: tree, d3.js, treeview

I would like to display a d3 tree e.g. on the left of the screen (tree_panel)and annotation for each leaf on the right (annotation_panel).

The thing is that the leaf annotation can become quite big.
So, I could put tree_panel+annotation_panel into one div and make it overflow:scroll.
Then, whenever I scroll to much to the right, the tree is not visible anymore.

Is there a way to separate tree and annotation so that one only scrolls in the annotation area?

I made the following image to make things easier: http://oi43.tinypic.com/2ihscpc.jpg

Thanks a lot for any pointers/help!

Fabian

Answer (score 0):

Can you use separate divs for the tree and the annotation (positioned side-by-side) with `overflow: scroll` only set on the annotation div?

Comment: Possibly. Then I guess I have to have one SVG per div. The nice thing with having just one SVG is that the annotation is assigned to the single leafs. So, if you collapse an internal node, all children and all its annotation is hidden. I guess I would loose that link when having two SVGs. In other words: When drawing the two divs, how do I make sure the annotation has the same x-coordinate as the corresponding leaf node?

Comment: All coordinates inside an SVG are relative to the top left corner so as long as both SVG's are the same size and are aligned properly, you should be able to use the same coordinates in both SVGs.  An alternative would be to use one SVG with a clipping path and then hook up an event handler to the scroll events so you can transform the annotation <g> relative to the scroll bar, but that sounds way more difficult to me.